# Making a controller for home page

Tags: php, cakephp

Can you tell me how to use a controller for home page because i'm trying to put a model's data in home.ctp (homepage view) with 
`<?php $this->user->find() ?>`but it returns

> Notice (8): Undefined property:
>   View::$user [APP\views\pages\home.ctp,
>   line 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the cookbook; it has some solid CakePHP tutorials, at http://book.cakephp.org/

You haven't really provided alot of information, but my guess is your Controller `uses` a model 'User', and you're putting `$this->user->find()` in your view, when it should be in your controller. In your controller's action you'll want/need to do something like this...

```
Users_Controller extends AppController {
    function index() {
        $arrayOfUsers = $this->User->find(...);
        $this->set('users', $arrayOfUsers);
    }
}
```

You can then - in your View - access 'users' like so:

```
pre($users);
```

... since you used the Controller method `set()` to send a variable `$users` to the view.

Comment: This should be UsersController (no underscore), and the debug function is pr() not pre()

Comment: Haha, ya, that's my bad. When I work in PHP without Cake, I always define my own version of pr which I call pre since I like function names to have at least one vowel :)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is create a new controller if that's the direction you want to go. If this is the only statement you have that requires data access, it might be worth faking it in only this method of the `PagesController`. For example, one of my projects' homepages is 99% static save for a list of featured events. Rather than move everything out to a new controller or even loading my `Event` model for the entire `PagesController` (where it's not needed), I just applied this solution in `PagesController::home()`:

```
$attractions = ClassRegistry::init ( 'Attraction' )->featured ( 10 );
```

Works great. If your page is more dynamic than mine, though, it may well be worth routing your homepage through a different controller (one that is more closely related to the data being displayed).

Answer (score 0):

The default controller for the home page i.e home.ctp view, is located in /cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php. This controller can be overriden by placing a copy in the controllers directory of your application as /app/controllers/pages_controller.php. You can then modify that controller as deem fit i.e. use models, inject variables to be used in the home page etc